# Azure multiple DbContext are ending up in same DB while having different connectionstring

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, azure-web-app-service, entity-framework-migrations

Locally everything works fine I have 2 context classes resulting in 2 database files

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-myTest-Identity.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-myTest-Identity;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="AppContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DataDB.mdf;Initial Catalog=DataDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

when I am publishing this to Azure, I need to provide 2 connection strings in the publish process.
In Azure I also created 2 different physical databases.

after publishing, VS2017 made changes to the connectionstrings as follows

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:escapegamessqlserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=identitydb;User Id=mylogin;Password=mypassword;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="AppContext" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:escapegamessqlserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=Datadb;User Id=mylogin;Password=mypassword;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="AppContext_DatabasePublish" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:escapegamessqlserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=Datadb;User ID=mylogin;Password=mypassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The publish process added 1 DatabasePublish connectionstring instead of 2 as I would expect.

**The Problem**

Both different contexts are inside 1 database.... the database *Datadb* is filled with both migrations and all tables. while I was expecting to have my user related migration on the *identitydb*.

I don't see how both contexts are ending up in the same physical database while having 2 different connectionstrings while locally it is working like a charm...

for completion, the data context is as follows

```
public class myAppContext : DbContext
{
    public myAppContext() : base("AppContext")
    {
    }
}
```

The identity part is more or less out of the box

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    static ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        // Set the database initializer which is run once during application start
        // This seeds the database with admin user credentials to the admin role
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<virusescapebe.ViewModels.RoleViewModel> RoleViewModels { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I checked this issue on my side. I published my web application via the VS publish wizard and manually configured the connection string for `AppContext` and `DefaultConnection` as follows:

[image]

Since I have selected Use this connection string at runtime (update destination web.config), you could leverage KUDU or Azure App Service Editor to view your modified web.config and check the connection string settings. Details you could follow [Understanding the Azure App Service Editor](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36467.understanding-the-azure-app-service-editor.aspx).

> Both different contexts are inside 1 database.... the database Datadb is filled with both migrations and all tables. while i was expecting to have my user related migration on the identitydb.

From your published web.config, you created a SQL Server (`escapegamessqlserver.database.windows.net`) and created a sql database named `identitydb` for your **DefaultConnection** connection string and a sql database named `Datadb` for your **AppContext** connection string. Though, I could not know where does the `AppContext_DatabasePublish` come from. But based on your `myAppContext` and `ApplicationDbContext`, the connection string has been pointed to the relevant azure sql database, and your application should work as expected.

Moreover, you could just configure the **DefaultConnection** and **AppContext** connection string under the "SETTINGS > Application settings" on Azure Portal instead of manually set the connection string for each of your DbContext. At this time, the connection string under your published web.config would not be modified, and app service would override the connection string settings based on your configuration on Azure Portal at run-time. For more details, you could follow [Configure web apps in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure).

Answer (score 0):

This is solved.
my settings in the web.config on the Azure side were overwritten by the Connectionstring option you can set in the Azure portal

App Services -> (name of app) -> Application Settings -> Connection Strings

there is a value mentioned as **defaultConnection** this one was overwriting my own settings in the web.config files